# Как вернуть значение AUTOINCREMENT id после вставки строки?

Tags: python, sqlite

`INSERT INTO clicks (user_id) VALUES ("305383784") returning click_id into i`

Хочу реализовать похожую команду в SQLite, взаимодйствую с бд при помощи Python, но не могу разобраться как вернуть `click_id` в переменную Python. Может команда `returning` вообще не поддерживается? `click_id` это `primary key` и `AUTOINCREMENT`

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('clicks.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = r'INSERT INTO clicks (user_id) VALUES ("305383784") returning click_id into i '
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе ту часть кода, где вы вставляете данные в SQLite таблицу...

Comment: conn = sqlite3.connect('clicks.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = r'INSERT INTO clicks (user_id) VALUES ("305383784")'
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
conn.close()

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопка "править" - код лучше вставлять непосредственно в вопрос...

Comment: но я после вставки хочу получать id он pk и ai, так что он увеличивается на один при каждой вставки, и что бы не брать последнюю строку каждый раз хотел бы его returning брать прям в insert запросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте атрибут `cursor.lastrowid`:

```
cursor.execute(sql)
last_id = cursor.lastrowid
conn.commit()
...
```

Comment: А не будет проблем, если сразу несколько пользователей взаимодействуют с бд и параллельно сделано несколько записей, получается что можно взять последнюю запись но это может быть не та запись которую сделал именно этот пользователь

Comment: На сколько я помню, SQLite вроде не поддерживает запись из нескольких потоков, а вот чтение - поддерживается.

Comment: @ИванДемьянов, ЕМНИП между `cursor.execute()` и `conn.commit()` таблица будет заблокирована для модификаций...

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо большое