# Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении новой записи в базу данных, эта самая новая запись определялась и дальше с ней можно было что-то делать?

Tags: python, база-данных, telebot, sqlite3

Леди и джентльмены, может быть кто-то знает ответ и сможет помочь!
Перекопал всю сеть на русском и английском - решения не нашел (возможно просто туп).

Суть:
Пишу на python телеграм бота (pyTelegramBotAPI).
Есть некая база данных на sqlite3.
Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении новой записи в базу данных, эта самая новая запись определялась и дальше с ней можно было что-то делать, например ботом отправлять в канал?

По логике, например, надо определить последний rowid (как?) или вообще сколько изначально было элементов в базе и проверить если добавлено новое, то делать то-то...
Но вот как это сделать? Или с sqlite3 такого не добиться?

UPD:
Сам спросил - сам ответил.
Получить номер последней записи - cursor.lastrowid

Comment: Непонятно, что вы имеете в виду под словом «определялась». Если вы хотите получить сгенерировавшийся autoincrement id, то такой вопрос на сайте уже был https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946329

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение AUTOINCREMENT id после вставки строки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946329/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-autoincrement-id-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)